# Copying and modifying array elements

Tags: java

Here is the original prompt:

> Write a loop that sets newScores to oldScores shifted once left, with element 0 copied to the end. Ex: If oldScores = {10, 20, 30, 40}, then newScores = {20, 30, 40, 10}.
>
> Note: These activities may test code with different test values. This activity will perform two tests, the first with a 4-element array (newScores = {10, 20, 30, 40}), the second with a 1-element array (newScores = {199}). See How to Use zyBooks.
>
> Also note: If the submitted code tries to access an invalid array element, such as newScores[9] for a 4-element array, the test may generate strange results. Or the test may crash and report "Program end never reached", in which case the system doesn't print the test case that caused the reported message.

This is the code that I have:

```
public class StudentScores {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
  final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
  int[] oldScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
  int[] newScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
  int i = 0;

  oldScores[0] = 10;
  oldScores[1] = 20;
  oldScores[2] = 30;
  oldScores[3] = 40;

  for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE - 1; i++) {
     newScores[3] = oldScores[0];
     newScores[i] = oldScores[i + 1]; 
  }

  for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
     System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();

  return;
 }
 }
```

This is my output:

Testing for oldScores = {10, 20, 30, 40}

Your output:  20 30 40 10

✖   Testing for oldScores = {199}

Expected output:  199

Your output:  0

Why am I getting 0 for my second output test?

Comment: You are hard-coding `3` instead of `SCORES_SIZE - 1`.

Comment: Changing newScores[3] to newScores[SCORES_SIZE - 1] still gives me 0 for the second output test

Comment: Ah, that's because the first `for` loop never runs, since `SCORES_SIZE - 1 == 0`, and `0 < 0` is false immediately. Move the `newScores[SCORES_SIZE - 1] = oldScores[0];` line outside the for loop.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for loop in which you copy the values from `oldscores` to `newscores` is never run in the case of `SCORES_SIZE == 1`, since `SCORES_SIZE - 1 == 0`, and `0 < 0` is false immediately.

Move the `newScores[SCORES_SIZE - 1] = oldScores[0];` line outside the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE - 1; i++) {
  newScores[i] = oldScores[i + 1]; 
}
newScores[SCORES_SIZE - 1] = oldScores[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you the only other check is an array with length one, simply use this

```
if(oldscores.length==1)
{newscores[0]=oldscores[0];
System.out.println(newscores[0]);
}
```

or even more simple,

```
if(oldscores.length==1)
{
    System.out.println(oldscores[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The top voted response on here is what I would have gone with. Here is another approach that yields the same results:

```
for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
      if (i == SCORES_SIZE - 1) {
         newScores[i] = oldScores[0]
      }
      else {
          newScores[i] = oldScores[i + 1];
      }
   }
```